What is the probability that a randomly chosen number from the $10$ numbers would be more than $7$?
The average of $10$ numbers is $7.5$.
What is the probability that a randomly chosen number from the $10$ numbers would be more than $7$?
This is the response from the author of the question.
$$\begin{align}
7.5, 7.5, \ldots, 7.5, 7.5 \qquad &\text{probability} = 10/10 \\
7, 7, \ldots, 7, 7, 12 \qquad &\text{probability} = 1/10.
\end{align}$$
My question is, are these the only 2 conditions for calculating the probability of a number greater than $7$?

Without any further information, all you can say is that at least one of the $10$ numbers is more than $7$, so the probability is $i/10$ for some integer $i$ from $1$ to $10$.

Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

This section of the Wikipedia plot summary on robust statistics may give you some insight.

Your ten numbers might be 0, 0, 0, $\ldots$, 0, and 75. Or they might be 8, 8, 8, $\ldots$, and 3. Or they might be 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, $\ldots$, 7.5, and 7.5. Or they might be…

I think the author of the question is trying to show you that the give information does not specify a unique probability.
